# does theano have something similar to the python dictionary that is iterable with symbolic keys?

Tags: theano

Basically, is the following toy problem possible?:

```py
def gpu(arg,name=None, _type=None):
    """Helper function to make variables shared"""
    aux = shared(np.array(arg,dtype=theano.config.floatX), name=name)
    if _type is None:
        return aux
    else:
        return T.cast(aux, _type)

init = [0 for each in range(10)] # weight initialization value
classes = list(range(1,4+1)) # I have four classes
weights = dict(zip(classes, [gpu(init, name=('w'+str(w))) for w in classes])) 

# Based on prior information I sometimes know a dataset contains
# no knowledge about certain classes, so in these cases I don't want
# want to "try" to learn(nothing) 
dont_care_about_these = [1,3] # I don't want to try to learn these classes
no_w3 = [w for w in classes if w not in dont_care_about_these] 

i_seq = T.vector(dtype='int8') 
outputs, updates = theano.scan(lambda i: ({weights[i]: weights[i]+1}), 
                               sequences=i_seq)

f = function(inputs=[i_seq], updates=updates) 
f(no_w3)

print(weights['w1'].get_value()) # Should still only contain zeros
print(weights['w2'].get_value()) # Should be updated
```

Here the problem is that I have inserted a dictionary for the scan updates, which then fails since it doesn't like theano.tensors as keys.

The reason I'm curious is that sometimes based on prior information I sometimes know a dataset contains no knowledge about certain classes, so in these cases I don't want want to "try" to learn (when I'm doomed to learn nothing).

#### Edit:  not really an answer, but a workaround.  Also see comments by  DrBwts below

```py
def gpu(arg,name=None, _type=None):
    """Helper function to make variables shared"""
    aux = shared(np.array(arg,dtype=theano.config.floatX), name=name)
    if _type is None:
        return aux
    else:
        return T.cast(aux, _type)

init = [0. for each in range(10)] # weight initialization value
classes = ['w'+str(i) for i in range(1,4+1)]
weights = dict(zip(classes, [init]*len(classes)))

dont_care_about_these = ['w1','w3'] # I don't want to try to learn these classes
picked = [w for w in classes if w not in dont_care_about_these] 
w_gpu = gpu([weights[key] for key in picked])
def replace_picked(w_gpu, picked):
    updated_weights = w_gpu.get_value()
    for i, key in enumerate(picked):
        weights[key] = updated_weights[i]

i_seq = T.vector(dtype='int8') 
outputs, updates = theano.scan(lambda i: ({w_gpu: T.inc_subtensor(w_gpu[i], 1.)}), 
                               sequences=i_seq)

f = function(inputs=[i_seq], updates=updates) 

f(range(len(picked)))
replace_picked(w_gpu,picked)
print(weights['w1'])
print(weights['w2'])
```

Comment: Are you asking about why the `theano.tensors` cant be used as keys?

Comment: Although, I would be curious about that too (think I have an idea though), I'm more asking about whether there would be somekind of theano functionality that would allow me to do the above...some kind of key functionality (array of pointers to theano variables) that could be scanned over...or something

Comment: I dont know the answer to your actual question : ) but the tensors cant be used as keys because they are mutable ie there is a possibility that their values can be changes which would be bad for any key values.

Comment: I hear what you're saying, but at the same time my ignorance can't really grasp why it's not possible to have a variable/tensor refer to an immutable key from a set of immutable keys.  I also posted a work around to my problem.  And thanks :)